# SSD and HDD Dual Boot

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, ssd

I have got Win 8 on my SSD and I want to install Ubuntu on my HDD. Can I? Thanks.
My SSD is 120 GB and when I try to access it gives this error in "trying Ubuntu" :

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu/2284BD1E84BCF57F: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/ubuntu/2284BD1E84BCF57F"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Close-voter(s): Is the issue here actually addressed, or even in the scope, of either of those questions or their answers? This seems separate ...and this has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question.

```
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
```

You have to shutdown Windows, not just hybernate it.

I think that on windows 8 (at least on some versions) this is an hidden option not showing up in the standard menus.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that Windows 8 doesn't shut down, but only hibernates. This means the Windows file system is still dirty after you switch off your computer. If you configure Windows 8 to shut down properly, then this problem will go away.

Answer (score -1):

Some links to more instructions.
Fast Startup off/hibernation

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

Force removal of hiberfil from Ubuntu

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/